# Node.js to query Couchbase view

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, couchbase, couchbase-view

I am new to using Couchbase but based on the documentation it seems that Couchbase is a good fit for my use case to store user data as documents. I have created a view on Couchbase which I am able to run and see the results in the dashboard. However when I run the view query from my node.js application, the server responds with an empty result.

```
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster("couchbase://localhost");
var bucket = cluster.openBucket("default");
var bmanager = bucket.manager();
var viewQuery = couchbase.ViewQuery;
var query = viewQuery.from('todoNew', 'ToDoNew'); //design doc name, view name

app.get("/todo/:New", function(req, res){ 
bucket.query(query, function(err, results) {
            for(i in results)
            console.log(results[i]);
            }); 
})
```

$ curl http://localhost:3000/todo/New
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:00 --:--:--     0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Here is an example json doc on Couchbase

```
{
"fromUserName": "Earl",
"toUserName": "Fred",
"description": "my description",
"id": 11,
"title": "Run marathon",
"status": "New"
}
```

And here is the view map function

```
function (doc, meta) {
 if(doc.status == 'New') {
 emit(meta.id, doc.toUserName, doc.title, doc.description);
 }
}
```

The above view function when executed from the couchbase dashboard returns docs like this

[image]

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Turns out, it was a typo on the view name. Sorry about the scare. The above code works.